# Transfer Text File in Web Server to Client

Tags: python

I try to use the following script to transfer a text file located in web server, to client (The text file is in UTF-16).

```
import cgi

print "Content-Type: text/plain"
print "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=TEST.txt"
print

filename = "C:\\TEST.TXT"
f = open(filename, 'r')
for line in f:
    print line
```

However, when I open up the downloaded file, the file is all having weird characters. I try to use `rb` flag, it doesn't either.

Is there anything I had missed out? What I wish is, the file (TEST.TXT) downloaded by the client by making query to the above script, will be exactly same as the one in server.

I also try to specific the encoding explicitly.

```
import cgi

print "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-16"
print "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=TEST.txt"
print

filename = "C:\\TEST.TXT"
f = open(filename, 'r')
for line in f:
    print line.encode('utf-16')
```

That doesn't work either.

---

**Original File on Server**
[image]

---

**Downloaded File**
[image]

---

I will have the [original text file](https://sites.google.com/site/yanchengcheok/Home/TEST.TXT?attredirects=0&d=1) being posted here in case you are interested to experiment it out.

Comment: I think the problem is that your text file does not begin with an UTF-16 BOM. I can't find any way to have python decode it properly, even using `codecs.open()`. Maybe you can add the proper BOM to the file?

Comment: But it is incorrect to say my text file is not being encoded properly, as Notepad, Notepad++, Firefox able to open my text file properly. FYI, the text file is generated using C++'s wostringstream

Comment: I didn't say your file wasn't properly encoded, but that I couldn't get python to properly decode it :) Since you're using python to read and transmit the file, it has to be able to decode it, that's why I suggested you add a BOM to the file.

Comment: The text file is written by a 3rd party C++ library, and was out of my control at current moment :)

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi, or possible I can treat it as a binary file? But, does "print" work for binary content?

Comment: @Yan Cheng, I don't think `rb` won't make any difference. The only way I can get it to work is by reading the whole file in one chunk, but it would probably be unwise to suggest that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ignore the text encoding, and transfer byte-to-byte to client with 0 modification.

```
#!c:/Python27/python.exe -u

import sys

print "Content-Type: text/plain;"
print "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=TEST.txt"
print

filename = "C:\\TEST.TXT"
f = open(filename, 'rb')
while True:
    data = f.read(4096)
    sys.stdout.write(data)
    if not data:
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you should specify the file [encoding](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset#declaring) in your `Content-Type` header:

```
print "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-16"
print "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=TEST.txt"
print
```

Then, you have to actually encode the lines in UTF-16 when sending them to the client:

```
print "\xff\xfe",  # send UTF-16 big-endian BOM
for line in f:
    print line.encode("utf-16be")
```

Comment: That's doesn't work either. I still get a weird file. Isn't the charset in header, just tell browser how it should render the text? What I want is, the file that I downloaded, is 100% same as the file found in server.

Comment: @Yan Cheng, yes, you also have to encode the file lines when transmitting them. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Yan Cheng, it seems `encode()` is adding a BOM for each line, which is not what we want. Answer updated, but I assumed big-endian UTF-16, are you perchance using little-endian?

Comment: Nope. Not working. I had posted the TEST.TXT to web, it will be easier for you to test out your solution.

Comment: And ofcourse, encode them while sending from the server to bytes and once it is received at the client end, decode them back using the same encoding to get the contents back.